# VBA Scape table nested in tab

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm trying unsuccessfully to get the data in the table with className="table recentRecap", circled in yellow in the graphic below.

I thought it might be as easy as:

```
set o = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("table recentRecap")
```

BUT that gets me an IHTMLElementCollection with no elements. Must I start at a higher level up? Where?

```
html
```

[image]

UPDATE

This is the XPath of the 1st element in the table I want:

```
//*[@id="com_fidelity_retail_dividendsoverview_recap"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

CSS Selector

```
 #com_fidelity_retail_dividendsoverview_recap > div > div > div > table
```

How do I use the path or selector in VBA code?

Comment: Are you trying with `IE` or `xmlhttp` request? If you are playing with `xmlhttp` then you should take a good look whether the content of that page is generated dynamically. If you are working with `IE` then check for the desired element after the webpage is fully loaded. Last of all, you should check whether the content is within any `iframe`. It's really difficult to guesstimate without facing the real web.

Comment: @novice-coder. using xmlhttp (ServerXMLHTTP60), and the page is definitely loaded. It's the navigation of the html that's got me stumped

Comment: Have you checked whether the desired element available in the `.responsetext` by using `debug.print`?

Comment: @novice-coder. Will try that next I guess. Assuming you are likely a better scraper than I, does the XPath I just posed as an edit help suggest how to get there?

Comment: I'm not good at `xpath`. I prefer to work with `css selector` instead. However, your defined `xpath` looks fragile. You can try like this          `//*[@id="com_fidelity_retail_dividendsoverview_recap"]//[contains(@class, "recentRecap")]//tr[2]//[@class="alignRight"]`. This `xpath` will not lead you to the exact location but it should find the first `td` of second `tr` within the table you are after.

Comment: @novice-coder, posted the selector. But can you get me to vba code from this?

Comment: Try like this: `Dim post As Object, HTML As New HTMLDocument
Set post = HTML.querySelectorAll("#com_fidelity_retail_dividendsoverview_recap table tr td")(0)
MsgBox post.innerText`